# Can the Burnham-Anderson book on multimodel inference be recommended?

Tags: model-selection, references, aic

As motivated by the recent change of the default model selection statistic in 
the R's forecast package from AIC to AICc, I am curious whether the latter is 
indeed applicable wherever the former is. I have a series of questions with this 
respect and here is the first one.

I know that to replace AIC with AICc everywhere is what [the well-known book in (1)](http://www.springer.com/statistics/statistical+theory+and+methods/book/978-0-387-95364-9) by 
Burnham and Anderson (non-statisticians), as [summarized here](http://www.sortie-nd.org/lme/Statistical%20Papers/Burnham_and_Anderson_2004_Multimodel_Inference.pdf), recommends. The book is sometimes uncritically referred to by younger statisticians, see e.g. comments to [this blog post by Rob Hyndman](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/aic/), but the statistician Brian Ripley advised in a radically different way:

```
“Burnham and Anderson (2002) is a book I would recommend people NOT read until 
they have read the primary literature. I see no evidence that the authors have 
actually read Akaike’s papers." [quoted from [AIC MYTHS AND MISUNDERSTANDINGS][4] by
Burnham-Anderson]
```

It does follow from what [Ripley writes](http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~ripley/) on the AIC and related theory that the warning should be taken seriously. I have both a good collection of Akaike's own papers and the Burnham-Anderson book. I will eventually have my own opinion on the quality of the book, but it will also help to know what the community of statisticians, both young and old, think on that. In particular, are there professors of statistics (or other good students of statistics) who explicitly recommended the book as a useful summary of knowledge on using AIC for model selection?

Reference:

(1) Burnham, K. P. & Anderson, D. R. Model selection and multimodel inference: a practical information-theoretic approach Springer, 2002

**PS.** In reply to the recent "answer" stating that "Dr.Burnham is a Ph.D. statistician" I'd like to add this clarification. Yes, by himself he is a statistician, a Fellow of the ASA and the recipient of numerous professional awards, including Distinguished Achievement Medal from the ASA. But who says he is not? All I have said above is that as a pair of authors they are not statisticians and the book reflects this fact.

Comment: The paper "AIC Myths and Misunderstandings" can be found [here](http://warnercnr.colostate.edu/~anderson/PDF_files/AIC%20Myths%20and%20Misunderstandings.pdf). I hadn't seen it (though I'd seen Ripley's comment before).

Comment: Thanks, the same link is in the question but I can't seem to edit the question to displayed it. I haven't seen Ripley's original comments, even though B-A mention multiple websites, so any links to Ripley's original comments would be useful too.

Comment: Ripley's original comment: [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2003-June/035526.html) (alternative archive if that doesn't work: [here](http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/help/03a/7263.html)). While I am fascinated by the question and would love to see it discussed, I do wonder if its scope might be too broad for a CV question as it stands.

Comment: Interesting. As to Ripley's 1st sentence, Akaike, H. A Bayesian analysis of the minimum AIC procedure Annals of the Institute of Statistical Mathematics, Springer, 1978, 30, 9-14 wrote "If  the  choice  of  one  single  model is not the sole purpose of the analysis of the data the average of the models with respect to the approximate posterior probability C exp {(-1/2)AIC  (k)}  will provide a better estimate of the true distribution of Y. In this type of application the 2k in the definition of AIC (k) may be adaptively modified...[questioning Ripley's 2nd sentence in the comment linked to]

Comment: The question provides links but I think it would be helpful for readers if the question itself gave some hint of what might be bad about the content of Burnham and Anderson's book. (If what they say is accurate, clear, helpful, etc., then it doesn't matter whether they actually read Akaike's papers.) Also, it seems to me that AIC and related methods are still controversial; if so, then any book presenting them will have detractors.  And a suggestion that everyone must read the original papers *before* reading a book that aspires to provide an introduction to a topic seems questionable.

Comment: @Mars I guess if I had known what might be bad about the B-A book, I would have asked a different question. I'll read what they write on Kullback–Leibler information in Wildlife Research 2001 journal of CSIRO publishing and perhaps the chap 2 of their book, but very likely it will be another question. As to reading Akaike's original papers, the general rule is that you should read what you cite (I think Rob Hyndman wrote a blog post on that a few years ago).

Comment: I've read Akaike's two main papers, and Schwarz's one on the BIC, and Burnham and Anderson's book (it's on my shelf right now), and also (as you see), Ripley's brief critique. I would like very much to see Ripley *explain* the criticism in detail (without the aspersions about who may have read what) -- as things stand, there's really nothing substantive for Burnham and Anderson to reply to. If there's something to it (and there may be for all I know), it deserves more than a few lines on an R-help mailing list.

Comment: @Gleb_b Ripley's views can be deduced from his 1996 book on pattern recognition, to which he referred to in that R list post, see e.g. chapter 2. The mathematical details and comments on 
other aspects of Akaike's work (e.g. what does A in AIC stands for) make me think he understands this area well and had read more than just a few of Akaike's papers.

Comment: @Glen_b [continued] On the other hand, the B-A book does not shun to go against the generally accepted. For example, while the authors understand the K-L is not symmetric in the sense 
that the measure from f to g is not the same as the measure from g to f (p.52), they write (same p.52) that "The K-L distance has also been called the K-L discrepancy, divergence, information, and number. We will treat these terms as synonyms, but tend to use distance or information in the material to follow."

Comment: Putting in a different two cents: How often do AIC and AICc give different advice? In my experience they suggest the same models.

Comment: @Peter Flom Good point. For example, table 7.6 of Rob Hyndman et al's monograph on Exponential Smoothing reports a comparison of five different ICc (including AIC and AICc) on M3 competition data using the MASE error measure. For linear models only, all but one of the nine reported pairs of values of MASE for AIC and AICc are indeed identical to the first decimal place. For both linear and non-linear models, the picture reported is different.

Comment: @Hibernating, OK, fair enough.  And of course you're right--one should have read what one cites, except in cases where it's made clear that what was read was only a secondary work that cites the original source.  Maybe it's worth mentioning Anderson's 2008 book, which provides a more condensed and probably easier introduction to AIC and related methods from his point of view.  It's a far from perfect book, but I found it useful. (I have not studied B-A carefully.)

Comment: @PeterFlom, I have had cases where AIC and AICc indicate different models. Usually, when trying to model annual frequency with only 10 - 15 observations, I find that is not uncommon for AIC to suggest the negative binomial but AICc to indicate the poisson. When $n$ is not large with respect to $k$, that last term can be meaningful. When $n >> k$, then there is little difference, which is why B&A recommend AICc always.

Answer (score 3):

The OP appears to be seeking a high-quality survey of high-quality statisticians to help assess whether one particular book is of high quality particularly with regards to the AIC versus AICc debate.  This site is not particularly geared towards systematic surveys.  Instead I'll try to address the underlying question directly.

The AIC and AICc both score models according to a heuristic tradeoff between model fit (in terms of the likelihood) and overfit (in terms of the number of parameters).  In this tradeoff, the AICc gives slightly greater penalty on the number of parameters.  Thus, the AICc always recommends in favor of models that are of complexity less-than-or-equal to the complexity of the best AIC model.  In this sense the relationship between the two is very simple, despite the horribly complicated arguments underlying their derivations.

The AIC and AICc are only two out of a large field of candidate information criteria, with the [BIC and DIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_criterion) being perhaps the leading alternatives.  The BIC is far more conservative (penalizing large numbers of model parameters) than either of the AIC or AICc in most cases.  The question of which criterion is the best is truly problem specific.  One could legitimately prefer an extremely conservative criterion in cases where robust out-of-sample prediction is needed.

FWIW, I found the conservatism level of the AICc to be *typically* preferable over the AIC in extensive simulation studies on the prediction error in capture-recapture models.